# jQuery load images from XML

Tags: jquery, xml, image, flash, load

I wan't to ask you that, can prettyphoto load images from xml file??

here is my function in html file:

```
    jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
$.fn.prettyPhoto();
});

function openLightbox(path) {

api_images=[path,'zdjecia/galeria/kategoria1/duze/image2.jpg','zdjecia/galeria/kategoria1/duze/image3.jpg'];
$.prettyPhoto.open(api_images);

}
```

and here is an XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<images>
<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image1.jpg" 
lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image1.jpg"/>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image2.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image2.jpg"/>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image3.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image3.jpg"/>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image4.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image4.jpg"/>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image5.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image5.jpg"/>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image6.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image6.jpg"/>

</images>
```

Is it possible to get the lightbox var??
Could anyone tell me how can i do it??

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jdLhR/4/

check this fiddle...it will load the images from xml file. hope it helps.

Comment: i'm trying to change it for images but without success :/

I don't know how to use it, i'm newbie in jquery i need it only to load images from xml. I'm creating a website in actionscript 3.0 and i wan't to open big image in prettyphoto so that's why i need to load rest of images from xml